# I want this piece of code to make a new sheet in an existing xlsx instead of making a new file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

As of Right Now this piece of code makes a new sheet and converts the CSV for me into an xlsx but it makes a whole new file, I want it to add a new sheet into an existing workbook and convert the CSV into xlsx there,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
df_new = pd.read_csv('Names.csv')
  
GFG = pd.ExcelWriter('Names.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(GFG, index = False)

  
GFG.save()
```

If you could write the whole code out it would be helpful as Im not fully aware of the pandas architecture

Comment: maybe you should write in `append mode`. See documentation for [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and example with `ExcelWriter(..., mode='a')`

Comment: Again, I am not familiar with the library, so can you list the whole code you are suggesting?

Comment: you have ALL in my comment - you have to add `mode='a'` - that's all.

Comment: and if you need more then see example in documentation.

Comment: @furas it gives me this error ValueError: Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!

Comment: see option `engine` in the same documentation - you may have to use `engine="openpyxl"` and it need to install module `openpyxl` - something like `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: @furas That helped, if you list it as an answer, I can select it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append new data you have to write in `append mode`

```
 GFG = pd.ExcelWriter('Names.xlsx', mode='a')
```

It seems it needs to use engine `openpyxl` instead of `xlsxwriter`

```
 GFG = pd.ExcelWriter('Names.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl')
```

and it may need to install module `openpyxl`

```
 pip install openpyxl
```

Maybe if you install `openpyxl` then it will use it automatically when you use `mode='a'`

---

If you want to add new sheet then you may need to use `sheet_name`

```
df_new.to_excel(GFG, index=False, sheet_name='First Sheet')

df_new.to_excel(GFG, index=False, sheet_name='Second Sheet')
```

---

Doc with examples: [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)